# DjangoRestFramework non-orm serializer and source

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

Problem:

I define serializer as:

```
from rest_framework import serializers


class ProductSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    no = serializers.CharField(source='identifier', required=True)
    product_name = serializers.CharField(required=False)
```

I want to use it like this:

```
payload = {
    'identifier': 'id-1',
    'product_name': 'aaa'

}

instance = ProductSerializer(data=payload)

instance.is_valid()

print(instance.data['no'])
```

As it happens source seems to be completely ignored if your serializers are not coupled with models. Or I am missing something?

Full code snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import django

from rest_framework import serializers

django.setup()


class ProductSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    no = serializers.CharField(source='identifier', required=True)
    product_name = serializers.CharField(required=False)


payload = {
    'identifier': 'id-1',
    'product_name': 'aaa'

}

instance = ProductSerializer(data=payload)

instance.is_valid()

print(instance.data['no'])
```